# ¿Porque en un fragment al pasar R.layout.fragment_blank ya no tengo que regresar el fragment inflado?

Tags: kotlin, android-fragment

No entiendo porque al pasar como parametro `R.layout.fragment_blank` ya no tengo que retornar nada para que se muestre el fragment en el activity. En el codigo todo esta comentado pero el fragment se muestra sin problemas:

```
class BlankFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_blank) {

    /*override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false)
    }*/

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo comentas te devolverá los valores por defecto de la función. Esta función es predeterminada y no la puedes borrar, solo se puede sobreescribir y tienes que devolver obligatoriamente una vista, si haces un `val view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false)` y pones que te especifique el tipo de variable te darás cuenta que es de tipo `View`, el resultado debería ser parecido a este: `val view:View!`. te recomiendo que visites: https://developer.android.com/courses/kotlin-android-fundamentals/overview